# Strong Type Assembly not prompted for password

Tags: vb.net

I have created a strong name assembly (with a password) and registered it in the GAC.  I have added a reference to the assembly in another project, however I was not prompted for a password.

Are you only prompted for a password if you want to convert the MSIL to VB.NET?

I have spent some time looking for an answer on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is a private device designed to restrict the usage of your `.snk` file, to help mitigate the risk that someone gets a copy of your `.snk` file and creates rogue assemblies that seem to come from your organisation.

However once the assembly is created, there is no further need to re-enter the password as long as you are rebuilding the assembly on the same machine. (You can also use the same `.snk` file with other projects on your machine without the need to enter the password)

But if you try to rebuild the assembly on another machine, Visual Studio will ask you for the `.snk` file's password when you try to rebuild it.

You definitely don't need to supply the password in order to reference the assembly.

You can read some more about it here http://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/

Comment: Thanks +1. That makes sense. I have just rebuilt the release all but I was not prompted for a password?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to re-enter the password if you are rebuilding on the same machine. You will need to enter the password if you try to use the `.snk` file on a different machine. I've edited my answer to reflect this.